# Can I find the assignee at a specific step in the workflow on Greenhopper?

Tags: issue-tracking, greenhopper

In Greenhopper, is it possible to find all issues that were assigned to a specific user at a specific step in the work flow?

We have a "testing" step, and I want to find all issues that we assigned to a specific user in that step. I have gone through the advanced search documentation, but there is nothing to this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
status was "Testing" by USERNAME
```

Unfortunately the `was` operator was only introduced in Greenhopper 5.5 and JIRA 4.3, which is newer than our version so I can't test it.

[Original answer was by [Tomas-S](https://answers.atlassian.com/users/4556/thomas-s/) on [Atlassian Answers](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/41496/can-i-find-the-assignee-at-a-specific-step-in-the-workflow-on-greenhopper).]